# How to conbine array to object in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I got two array here:

```
let arr1 = [
  {
    sockets: 0,
    implicitMods: [
      '+2 to Level of Socketed AoE Gems',
      '+2 to Level of Socketed Trap or Mine Gems'
    ],
    explicitMods: [], // arr2[0] in here
  },
  {
    sockets: 3,
    implicitMods: [ 'Secrets of Suffering' ],
    explicitMods: [], // arr2[1] in here
  }
]

let arr2 = [
  [
    [ 'explicit.stat_2866361420' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_1978899297' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_2290031712' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_4294267596' ]
  ],
  [
    [ 'explicit.stat_2974417149' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_3556824919' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_789117908' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_124131830' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_1600707273' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_3742945352' ]
  ]
]
```

i want put `arr2[0]` to arr1's first `explicitMods` and `arr2[1]` to arr1's second `explicitMods`, how i can get object order in array (e.g.arr1[0]==={first object}, arr1[1]==={second object})? and how to achieve my goal?

i tried to use

```
arr1.map(el=>el.explicitMods = arr2)
```

and result is explicitMods: [[Array], [Array]]

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: i tried to use arr1.map(el=>el.explicitMods = arr2) and result is `explicitMods: [[Array], [Array]]` @Yogi

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas sorry im just start learning this, i tried to google it, i dont konw what should i descript my question to goole. i'll try my best next time before asking question here. thx

Comment: You need to know how to work with arrays (access elements, store values, iterate over the elements). That's part of every JS tutorial. So you should at least be able to show a loop that tries to access/store something -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @001 any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create two for loops like this:

```js
//For loop that starts from 0 to the length of the input array(arr2)
for(let i=0; i<arr2.length; i++){
//Save the expMods in i position temporally
    let expMods = arr1[i].explicitMods;
    //Make a loop for the first element of the arr2 which is also an array
    for(let j=0; j<arr2[i].length; j++){
    //Get the arr2 at current i pos and push into expMods the arr2[i][j]
       let temp = arr2[i];
       expMods.push(temp[j]);
    }
}
```

I've tested into the console and it worked, let me know

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    sockets: 0,
    implicitMods: [
      '+2 to Level of Socketed AoE Gems',
      '+2 to Level of Socketed Trap or Mine Gems'
    ],
    explicitMods: [], // arr2[0] in here
  },
  {
    sockets: 3,
    implicitMods: [ 'Secrets of Suffering' ],
    explicitMods: [], // arr2[1] in here
  }
]

const arr2 = [
  [
    [ 'explicit.stat_2866361420' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_1978899297' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_2290031712' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_4294267596' ]
  ],
  [
    [ 'explicit.stat_2974417149' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_3556824919' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_789117908' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_124131830' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_1600707273' ],
    [ 'explicit.stat_3742945352' ]
  ]
];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  const item1 = arr1[i];
  const item2 = arr2[i];
  //item1.explicitMods.push(...item2);
  item1.explicitMods.push(...item2.flat());
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()`, grab the index and use it to add the corresponding value.

```js
let arr1 = [{ sockets: 0, implicitMods: ['+2 to Level of Socketed AoE Gems', '+2 to Level of Socketed Trap or Mine Gems'], explicitMods: [], }, { sockets: 3, implicitMods: ['Secrets of Suffering'], explicitMods: [], }];
let arr2 = [[['explicit.stat_2866361420'], ['explicit.stat_1978899297'], ['explicit.stat_2290031712'], ['explicit.stat_4294267596']], [['explicit.stat_2974417149'], ['explicit.stat_3556824919'], ['explicit.stat_789117908'], ['explicit.stat_124131830'], ['explicit.stat_1600707273'], ['explicit.stat_3742945352']]];

const result = arr1.map((v, i) => {
  return {
    ...v,
    explicitMods: arr2[i]
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
arr1.map((el, index)=> el.explicitMods = arr2[index])
```

Comment: `forEach` is more appropriate here. (don't use `map()` unless you need the returned array)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.